# Where can I find schtasks.exe exit codes

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

Where can I find the documentation for exit/return/error codes for the schtasks.exe ?
MS's documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx) doesn't have any references regarding these.

Thanks !
Shai.

Answer (score 1):

ExitCode 0 if Schtasks was successful
ExitCode 1 if Error occurs

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any, or if there are, they are not made public.

You can use some programs such as .NET to read the status, but that is off topic here.